# ESLint with Babel plugin-proposal-export-default-from

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, eslint

I just added [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from) babel plugin in order to make use of that `export aDefault from 'a/module'`.

Works well as I can import such an export from other files but eslint isn't sparing me. It highlights my export statement ruthlessly.

Do we have an eslint plugin for that, or how should I go about it? My `.eslintrc.yaml` currently extends `standard`.

Comment: Highlights the statement with what message?

Comment: @Bergi, `1128: Declaration or statement expected.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have exhausted my options; including having `babel-eslint` as the parser in the `eslintrc.json` file.

In case anyone lands here with a similar issue, I decided to adapt the standard specification, with some aliasing, and forget about the babel syntax;

```js
// index.js

export { default as PreferredName, aNamedExport } from 'a/module';
export { default as AnotherPreferredName, anotherNamedExport } from 'another/module';

// or export all the named exports from another/module.js
export * from 'another/module'; // this won't export the default. It will also throw an error if anotherNamedExport has already been exported from another/module.js as above
```

Answer (score 0):

.eslintrc

```
"comma-dangle": [
  "error", 
  { 
    "exports": "never",
    "imports": "never"
  }
]
```